# calendar arithmetic - repitation (also by year change)

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

I would have a really special question concerning calendar arithmetic.
I have e.g. three weeks anywhere in a year - the red ones in the graphic at the bottom. 
Now I will calculate e.g. week 45 (in a calendar or anywhere else).

Calendar week 45 belongs to calendar week 24 (always adding three weeks starting from the red ones)

> *22* 23 **24**,
>     25 26 27,
>     *28* 29 30,
>
> ...
>   43 44 **45**

-> Therefore Monday and Sunday should be marked for calendar week 45.
E.g. week 28 (28 belongs to 22) than Monday and Friday should be marked.

So far so good. If I have to handle one year, it is no problem. The problem is, if I switch to the next year e.g. to calendar week 15 of the next year.

I need this in my application where I use Java and the Jodatime library.

Sorry for the explanation - its not possible to explain it in a better way.

Thanks a lot for your help!
All the best!

[[image: Calendar]]

Comment: What do you mean by "correspond"? Can you [edit] your question to clarify?

Comment: To put it bluntly, your description reads like gibberish.

Comment: Sorry for my description, I have improved it a little bit but it was hard for me to expain - I hope now it is understandable.